# Issue controlling game frame rate C++

Tags: c++, frame-rate, game-loop

I'm programming a game in C++ and I'm having trouble creating a way so that the game only updates 60 times per second. The code I have written looks like it should work but the frame rate actually ends up as 44 frames per second instead of 60.

```
const int               FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
const int               FRAME_CONTROL = (1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
double                  lastFrameTime;
double                  currentFrameTime;

void GameLoop()
{
    currentFrameTime = GetTickCount();

    if ((currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime) >= FRAME_CONTROL)
    {
        lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

        // Update Game.
    }
}
```

So yeah, it should be 60 frames but it actually runs at 44. And the class I'm using to count the frame rate works perfectly in other programs which already have a capped frame rate.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Is `// Update Game` capable of running in less that a sixtieth of a second?

Comment: Is it possible that your game is too intensive and just doesn't manage 60 FPS?

Comment: Yes, without the frame rate control it will happily run at around 500 frames per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its due to the resolution of `getTickCount`. That function only gives 10-16 ms resolution [Microsoft GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I'll read about high resolution timers, unless you know a good working one you can point me to?

Comment: You can include <omp.h> and use omp_get_wtime(). It returns time in seconds with very high precision.

Comment: I use GLFW, and it includes a high resolution timer.